# how to sculpt precisely in detail

Tags: modeling, mesh, add-on, sculpting, sculpt

i have a model and i would like to sculpt detail on top of it, the goal is these lines that i would sculpt like tubing all around the model, so since that's the case i want to make the lines straight and precise, how would i sculpt evenly and consistently in perfect straight lines, is there a free plugin that helps you to sculpt? i don't want any other plugin as i have tried and failed to work on other plugins, i feel like sculpting would be the better choice

[image]

liker if you look at the fortnite skins neck, imagine this, but for the whole body, how would i sculpt this, just adding as well that it will be a lot thinner than the tubes on his neck

Comment: I would make these details using normal maps

Answer (score 1):

It may be easier to model those lines and details with hard surface than with sculpting. I don't know any addon that helps you to draw straight lines but when I sculpt I am using this:
[image]

It stabilizes your brush and make it easier for you to make straight and nice lines ,but it still takes some time to learn as well.

Comment: ok then, and not to be a nuisance, but if the model is more low poly than this image, how do i make it very detailed?

Comment: Same as @Crantisz suggested, use 2 meshes... 1st is your low poly version of this figure... duplicate it, hide original and use duplicate for sculpting, use subdiv or dyntopo in sculpting to make fine and very detailed details and then bake this high poly object into your low poly object as height map (there are plenty of tutorials for this)

Comment: ah i see, thank you very much, i will look up tutorials and learn, i appreciate it